# Source Header (first row) are dates in a FF then mapping success else fail

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a requirement  where my source  flat file with first row with dates, second row with field names and so on and i am reading it as one string and loading into target table.
So I need to do a unit test where if the source file don't have dates in there first row but have some thing else then i want to fail my mapping else success.

Example of source file:

```
"2015-05-23","2015-06-05"
"carrier","contract",'Group",'Name",'record"
"1234","abcd","4567","kiran","1".
```

How do I approach this logic in Informatica, please share your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a substring of the first line and check if it contains a date using the IS_DATE function.

ex. `IS_DATE(SUBSTR(input, 2, 10),'YYYY-MM-DD')`

Then, if the above return false, use the ABORT function to fail the workflow.

Comment: Hi , i have done the same I said iif(seq_num=1,to_date(substr(date,2,10),'YYYY-MM-DD'),null) here seq_num is to identify if the file so on first line that I stow number kind off..now if the condition returns null ,then my mapping should fail..so do I need any mapping ow workflow veriable ..if so how to use can you please explain.

Comment: You can try the ABORT function in an expression.

Comment: Abort function is throwing error Message Code: TT_11132
Message: Transformation [exp_Start_and_End_dates] had an error evaluating output column [o_DATE_bgn]. Error message is [<<Expression Fatal Error>> [ABORT]: DATES NOT MATCHED
... t:ABORT(s:'DATES NOT MATCHED')]. this is what i did

Comment: Abort function is throwing error Message Code: TT_11132
Message: Transformation [exp_Start_and_End_dates] had an error evaluating output column [o_DATE_bgn].  this is what i did, i created a variable port    :date_ bgn=IS_DATE(SUBSTR(Record, 2, 10))which is an integer data type output port:IIF(OUT_SEQ=1 AND DATE_bgn = 1, TO_DATE(SUBSTR(Record,2,10),'YYYY-MM-DD'),ABORT('DATES NOT MATCHED')) which is an date/time data type.  out seq=1 is used to check if the row number is 1 or not.  i guess i am doing it wrong, please share your inputs.

Comment: Put the format in IS_DATE function as well. Otherwise, IS_DATE uses the default format 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'. I have also corrected it in the answer.

Comment: On the positive side, looks like your ABORT function is working fine. It is producing the error and failing the session.

Comment: it still throwing error with message Message Code: TT_11132
Message: Transformation [exp_Start_and_End_dates] had an error evaluating output column [o_DATE_bgn]. Error message is [<<Expression Fatal Error>> [ABORT]: NO HEADER DATES
... t:ABORT(s:'NO HEADER DATES')].

Comment: when the file has dates on it

Comment: i dedugged and what i could see is when the seq_num is 1 it is returning dates when seq_num is 2 dates are null so it is aborting the mapping,

Comment: change it to a variable port v_date_bgn: IIF(OUT_SEQ=1, IIF(DATE_bgn = 1, TO_DATE(SUBSTR(Record,2,10),'YYYY-MM-DD'),ABORT('DATES NOT MATCHED')),v_date_bgn)

Answer (score 0):

You can create two separate pipelines -

- one which picks up first row from the file, check if its a date and abort whole flow if it isn't. Picking up first row - you can use sequence generator to determine if that is first row or not. then use IS_DATE(SUBSTR(input, 2, 10),'YYYY-MM-DD') and ABORT.
- Second pipeline will process the data as usual.